# bash is zipping entire home

Tags: bash, centos6

I am trying to back up a all `world*` folders from `/home/mc/server/` and drop the zipped in `/home/mc/backup/`

```
#!/bin/bash
moment=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
backup="/home/mc/backup/map$moment.zip"
map="/home/mc/server/world*"
zipping="zip -r -9 $backup $map"
eval $zipping
```

The zipped file is created in `backup` folder as expected, but when I unzipped it contants the entire /home dir. I am running this bash in two ways:

1. Manually
2. Using user's crontab

Finally, If I put an echo of `echo $zipping` this prints correctly the command that I need to trigger. What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of using eval, maybe try `\`zip -r -9 $backup $map\``? (With backticks?)

Comment: @AlexanderKohler, the bash is printing an error with that change: `adding:: command not found`

Comment: @AlexanderKohler That attempts to run the *output* of the `zip` command as another command. `$zipping` by itself would kinda-sorta work (although without parsing shell constructs like pipes or compound commands).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to use `eval` here (and no, justifying it on DRY grounds if you want to both log a command line and subsequently execute it does not count as a good reason IMO.)

Define a function and call it with the appropriate arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
moment=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")

zipping () {
  output=$1
  shift
  zip -r -9 "$output" "$@"
}

zipping "/home/mc/backup/map$moment.zip" /home/mc/server/world*
```

(I'll admit, I don't know what is causing the behavior you report, but it would be better to confirm it is not somehow specific to the use of `eval` before trying to diagnose it further.)

Comment: It is curious, because when I unzipped it, it contains the `/home` too, but in this way it just compress the files that I really need, looks like it keeps the enrtire path

Comment: In some sense, `/home` *is* in the archive, since extracting the archive would create `/home` if necessary. Other subdirectories in `/home` aside from `me` should *not* be present, though.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you so much for help and explaination.